# Will the "Documentation" feature become available to us here?

Tags: support, feature-request

I know it's currently in beta on Stack Overflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation

I know a community documentation effort was or is ongoing on https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/ - and was wondering if there was any interest in bringing it in here. To further bolster this site as a true hub of community knowledge.

That's a separate question I guess - so for now, just this: Will Documentation be available?  or can we request that it be activated here?